# Excel Macro to help identify duplicate lines of data

Tags: excel

I was wondering if anyone has any information on writing a macro to help with comparing two sets of data that may contain the same list of values. Here's the deal:

First, we make the Excel file with the raw data. This raw data, when extracted from the source, always contains all the data collected, even what we have collected previously. There are nine columns, each pertaining two an individual variable. Column A has subject number, and the following columns contain data pertaining to that subject (hence, one row of data from columns A to I pertains to the data for one subject). Once we have the raw data in the excel file, we need to move the new data from this pool of all the data to a series of master spreadsheets that are separated according to different respondents and time points. I want to be able to find a way to compare each of the master spreadsheets individually to the raw data Excel file to highlight any rows of data that were previously transferred. This would make it much easier to move the new data to the master spreadsheets.

Any ideas? Feel free to ask me if there is something that needs more clarification. Thanks - Adrienne

Comment: You can use Conditional Formatting in order to highlight duplicates, as explained here: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/find-duplicates.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Conditional Formatting in order to highlight duplicates (as explained here: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/find-duplicates.html), or to use a VBA Macro as shown in the code snippet below:

```
Sub FindDups ()
   '
   ' NOTE: You must select the first cell in the column and
   ' make sure that the column is sorted before running this macro
   '
   ScreenUpdating = False
   FirstItem = ActiveCell.Value
   SecondItem = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value
   Offsetcount = 1
   Do While ActiveCell <> ""
      If FirstItem = SecondItem Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(Offsetcount,0).Interior.Color = RGB(255,0,0)
        Offsetcount = Offsetcount + 1
        SecondItem = ActiveCell.Offset(Offsetcount, 0).Value
      Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(Offsetcount, 0).Select
        FirstItem = ActiveCell.Value
        SecondItem = ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Value
        Offsetcount = 1
      End If
   Loop
   ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/KB/213355

Hope this will help. Rgds,

Answer (score 0):

The concept for this is that there are two databases with the same structure that needs to be compared and analyzed for matches, differences, conflicts, etc.   When it's finished running you can look through the sheets created to evaluate the conflicts and resolve them.  At that stage, you can copy some rows manually after you've made some decisions.  The heavy lifting is in the code.

It will compare the two and color format the results.

**SETUP:**

You will need to have the following sheets setup:  And manually copy the header rows

**DatabaseA:**  The entire contents of The first database to compare

**DatabaseB:**  The entire contents of The second database to compare

**Similar:**    This will take all the records the two have in COMMON

**UniqueA:**    These are rows that only appear in dbA

**UniqueB:**    only appearing in dbB

**ConflictA:**  Both Conflict pages are the SAME records, with some entries missing on one and filled in the other.  Conflict A highlights cells in "ORANGE" that are missing from B but present in A, and "RED" with values that are present in both databases but have different values.

**ConflictB:**  The same as ConflictA except the cells are "BLUE"

**ConflictResolution:**  This takes all the records from ConflictA & B and merges them where they can be.  ie, similar matching records with some values present in one database, not in the other.

**ConflictDoubles:**  Gives a report of the records present in both Databases, and need evaluated because the values are conflicting.  Someone needs to choose with their brain.

All of those sheets are empty except the header rows to match Database A & B.  Copy your data into those two sheets.  (SAME COLUMN LAYOUTS ON ALL SHEETS)

**TESTED**

```
Sub DataMatch()

Dim lastRowA As Long
Dim lastRowB As Long
Dim lastRowUA As Long
Dim lastRowUB As Long
Dim lastRowSim As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim lastRowCon As Long

Dim rng As Range
Dim matchCount As Integer

Dim sA As String
Dim sB As String
Dim uA As String
Dim uB As String
Dim sim As String
Dim conA As String
Dim conB As String

Dim rA As Integer
Dim rB As Integer
Dim rUA As Integer
Dim rUB As Integer
Dim rSim As Integer
Dim rCon As Integer

Dim tCol As Integer

Dim isConflict As Boolean
Dim ConflictListA() As Variant
Dim ConflictListB() As Variant

Dim isMatching As Boolean

'SET SHEET NAMES
sA = "DatabaseA"
sB = "DatabaseB"
sim = "Similar"
uA = "UniqueA"
uB = "UniqueB"
conA = "ConflictA"
conB = "ConflictB"

'Column B is the Key Column
lastRowA = Sheets(sA).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRowB = Sheets(sB).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRowUA = Sheets(uA).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRowUB = Sheets(uB).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRowSim = Sheets(sim).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

LastCol = Sheets(sA).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column '114

'Set the First Row for the target sheets
rCon = 2
rSim = 2
rUA = 2
rUB = 2


'------------------------LOOP THROUGH SHEET A AND CHECK FOR UNIQUE ENTRIES------------------------'
Set rng = Sheets(sB).Range("B2:B" & lastRowB)

For rA = 2 To lastRowA
    tKey = Sheets(sA).Cells(rA, 2)
    matchCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, tKey)

   'Check to see if there are any matches on SourceSheet2

    If matchCount = 0 Then
    'There are NO matches.  Copy Entire Row to UniqueA
        For x = 1 To LastCol
            Sheets(uA).Cells(rUA, x) = Sheets(sA).Cells(rA, x)
        Next x
        rUA = rUA + 1
    Else
       'Get first matching occurance on the SourceSheet2
        m = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(tKey, rng, 0)
        'Get Absolute Row number of that match
        rB = m + 1    ' This takes into account the Header Row, as index 1 is Row 2 of the search Range

        'Compare to make sure they are complete matches.  If there is a conflict, send to Conflict Sheets
        For tCol = 1 To LastCol
            If Sheets(sA).Cells(rA, tCol) = Sheets(sB).Cells(rB, tCol) Then
                isConflict = False
            Else
                isConflict = True

                'Copy Data to ConflictA and ConflictB
                For x = 1 To LastCol
                    Sheets(conA).Cells(rCon, x) = Sheets(sA).Cells(rA, x)
                    Sheets(conB).Cells(rCon, x) = Sheets(sB).Cells(rB, x)
                Next x
                rCon = rCon + 1

                Exit For     
            End If
        Next tCol

        'Similar records, adding to Similar Sheet
        If isConflict = False Then
            For x = 1 To LastCol
                Sheets(sim).Cells(rSim, x) = Sheets(sA).Cells(rA, x)
            Next x
            rSim = rSim + 1
        End If

    End If

Next rA

'------------------------LOOP THROUGH SHEET B AND CHECK FOR UNIQUE ENTRIES------------------------'

Set rng = Sheets(sA).Range("B2:B" & lastRowA)

For rB = 2 To lastRowB
    tKey = Sheets(sB).Cells(rB, 2)
    matchCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, tKey)

   'Check to see if there are any matches on SourceSheet2

    If matchCount = 0 Then
    'There are NO matches.  Copy Entire Row to UniqueB
        For x = 1 To LastCol
            Sheets(uB).Cells(rUB, x) = Sheets(sB).Cells(rB, x)
        Next x
        rUB = rUB + 1
    End If

Next rB

Call HighlightDifference

End Sub

Private Sub HighlightDifference()

Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim ConflictRows() As String
Dim cDRow As Integer
Dim blDimensioned As Boolean

cDRow = 2

blDimensioned = False

LastRow = Sheets("ConflictA").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = Sheets("ConflictA").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column '114

For r = 2 To LastRow

    For c = 1 To LastCol

        If Sheets("ConflictA").Cells(r, c) <> Sheets("ConflictB").Cells(r, c) Then
            Sheets("ConflictA").Cells(r, c).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
            Sheets("ConflictB").Cells(r, c).Interior.ColorIndex = 37

            If Sheets("ConflictA").Cells(r, c) <> "" And Sheets("ConflictB").Cells(r, c) <> "" Then
                'MsgBox ("Both sheets have values in Cells.(" & r & ", " & c & ")" & vbNewLine & _
                    "Adding row to exception list to create new table")
                Sheets("ConflictA").Cells(r, c).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Sheets("ConflictB").Cells(r, c).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Sheets("ConflictA").Cells(r, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Sheets("ConflictB").Cells(r, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

                'Sheets("ConflictResolution").Cells(r, c) = Sheets("ConflictA").Cells(r, c) & " / " & Sheets("ConflictB").Cells(r, c)
                Sheets("ConflictResolution").Cells(r, c) = "CONFLICT"
                Sheets("ConflictResolution").Cells(r, c).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Sheets("ConflictResolution").Cells(r, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3


                'Add the row of the Conflict Resolution Sheet to exceptions to Note later with Color
                If blDimensioned = True Then
                    ReDim Preserve ConflictRows(0 To UBound(ConflictRows) + 1) As String
                Else
                    ReDim ConflictRows(0 To 0) As String
                    blDimensioned = True
                End If

                ConflictRows(UBound(ConflictRows)) = r


                'Add Separate Row for Each Source to ConflictDoubles
                For cDCol = 1 To LastCol
                    Sheets("ConflictDoubles").Cells(cDRow, cDCol) = Sheets("ConflictA").Cells(r, cDCol)
                    Sheets("ConflictDoubles").Cells(cDRow, cDCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 40

                    Sheets("ConflictDoubles").Cells(cDRow + 1, cDCol) = Sheets("ConflictB").Cells(r, cDCol)
                    Sheets("ConflictDoubles").Cells(cDRow + 1, cDCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                Next cDCol
                cDRow = cDRow + 2

            End If

            If Sheets("ConflictA").Cells(r, c) = "" Then
                Sheets("ConflictResolution").Cells(r, c) = Sheets("ConflictB").Cells(r, c)
                Sheets("ConflictResolution").Cells(r, c).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
            ElseIf Sheets("ConflictB").Cells(r, c) = "" And Sheets("ConflictA").Cells(r, c) <> "" Then
                Sheets("ConflictResolution").Cells(r, c) = Sheets("ConflictA").Cells(r, c)
                Sheets("ConflictResolution").Cells(r, c).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
            End If

        ElseIf Sheets("ConflictA").Cells(r, c) = Sheets("ConflictB").Cells(r, c) Then
            Sheets("ConflictResolution").Cells(r, c) = Sheets("ConflictA").Cells(r, c)
        End If

    Next c

Next r
Call ShowDoubles
End Sub

Private Sub ShowDoubles()

Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim LastCol As Integer

LastRow = Sheets("ConflictDoubles").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = Sheets("ConflictDoubles").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column '114
r = 2
Do While r <= LastRow
    For c = 1 To LastCol
        If Sheets("ConflictDoubles").Cells(r, c) <> Sheets("ConflictDoubles").Cells(r + 1, c) Then
            Sheets("ConflictDoubles").Cells(r, c).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Sheets("ConflictDoubles").Cells(r + 1, c).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next c
    r = r + 2
Loop

End Sub
```

**Example of ConflictA** highlighting the cells that have conflicts that are Empty in one version and not in the other.
**ConflictA**

[image: ConflictA]

**ConflictB**

[image: ConflictB]

**Conflict Resolution**

[image]